# Firefox addon's icon gone after restart, how to get them back

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Today I found my firefox addon's icons are all gone, nowhere to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by disabling and re-enabling each addon. The icons all came back.